# Saving each file in for loop gives ERROR 000872?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7

I am beginner to Python programming. I know, I am asking a really silly question. I am trying to extract DEM for each watershed from a bigger DEM. Therefore, I am using extract by mask. The bigger DEM is in raster format whereas the watershed boundaries are polygon. I have the following python code which works well. However, I am unable to save each watershed DEM after extraction in the loop. using my code I can only save the 1st watershed,then it says"ERROR 000872: Output Raster: Output C:\Subhasis\Project-Biological_monitoring\LIDAR-DEM\i exists. It cannot be overwritten since overwrite is off".

Code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#set work environment
env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/Individual_watershed/Watershed_Final"

outws="C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/LIDAR-DEM"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#List shapefile
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for i in fcList:
    inRaster="nj10ftffil"
    outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(inRaster, i)
    #outname=os.path.join(outws,i)
    #outExtractByMask.save(outname)
    outExtractByMask.save("C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/LIDAR-DEM/i")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to come up with a unique name for each raster output. In doing this, you need to remove the ".shp" extension from the shapefile in order to use this in the output raster name.  Also, keep in mind that you need to be aware of input and output raster extensions in your script.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#set work environment
env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/Individual_watershed/Watershed_Final"

# Make sure to specify the correct extension for the raster (e.g. ".tif")
# No extension = Esri Grid format
inRaster = 'C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/LIDAR-DEM/nj10ftffil'  # Your DEM
outws="C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/LIDAR-DEM"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#List shapefile
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcList:
    outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(inRaster, fc)
    outname=os.path.join(outws,fc.strip(".")[0] + ".tif") # Remove ".shp" extension
    outExtractByMask.save(outname)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code is working with slight modification.

Answer (score 0):

my modification in the code to output correctly

```
for fc in fcList:
  out_euc = arcpy.sa.EucDistance(fc, 500000, 30)
  ext = os.path.splitext(fc)
  outname=os.path.join(output_path, ext[0] + ".tif") # Remove ".shp" extension
  out_euc.save(outname)
```